# Spinner options for a math calc with other inputs

Tags: math, input, integer, spinner, calc

I have a spinner drop down list in lbs or kgs how do I then get the user to input the numerical value, so I can then do a math calc with other spinner inputs .
bit of a novice so any help appreciated.

Comment: hi, maybe add a text box to record the user input and a button to perform the calculation?